# Where is the RHEL version 5 Developer Guide?

Tags: api, redhat, rhel, abi, rhel5

I found the "Developer Guide" for RHEL version 6 located at: https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/ --> click on the Developer Guide link.

However when you scroll down further to the RHEL version 5 documentation I can't find an equivalent Developer Guide. **Is there an equivalent Developer Guide for RHEL 5 documentation?**

**If there is not an equivalent Developer Guide in RHEL version 5 documentation, what RHEL 5 document/section talks about the 'Application Compatibility' (which covers things like API and ABI compatibility spanning major/minor releases*)?**

* NOTE: in RHEL 6 the Applicaiton Compatibility is covered in Section 3.2 of the Developer Guide. ([RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/) --> version 6 --> [Developer Guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/index.html) --> [Section 3.2](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/lib.compatibility.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Developer Guide for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and there is no direct equivalent either: the Developer Guide was introduced with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 as a completely new book. There is, however, a [Knowledgebase article](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/119073) that provides a link to the [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Application Compatibility Specification](http://www.redhat.com/f/pdf/rhel/RHEL6_App_Compatibility_WP.pdf) document.